# Max buying price at vendors

Tags: diablo-ii

How much can items sold at vendors cost at most?

I recently sold an armor that would cost me more than 3.6 million gold to buy back (which exceeds my total max gold). I know I can lower prices and with gheed/edge I could rebuy it if I wanted. but I was wondering if prices can even surpass the limit of total gold after reducing vendor prices.

I didn't find anything on that topic searching on here, on Arreat Summit or with google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if prices even have top bound, but looks like +X Skills items are the most expensive. For example, [in this thread](https://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/whats-the-most-expensive-item-to-buy-back-from-npc.226790/) I've found item for 12 millions:

[image: item for 12 millions screenshot]